# How to get the greatest area of the shown rectangle above this $x^3$ curve?

Tags: calculus

[image]
[Graph of function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LamaN.jpg)

I tried problems of maximizing containing graphs before but they were quadratic functions like $x^2$, I do not know what to do with this one : $f(x) = x^3$  if not clear in the above diagram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell from the picture but I am assuming $f(x) = x^3$ with a horizontal boundary at $y=32$.

Let $s$ be the (horizontal) side length of the rectangle. Then the area of the rectangle is equal to $A = s \cdot (32 - f(s))$, and since $f(x) = x^3$, we have $A = s \cdot (32 - s^3)$.

The derivative is equal to $32 - 4s^3$, which has root $s=2$ when we set it to $0$.

Therefore the maximum area is $A = 2 \cdot (32 - 2^3) = 48$

Comment: that's pretty simple but what I don't understand why is OA considered the length of f(x), maybe I'm missing some background?

Comment: $f(x)$ takes your $x$ values and returns a $y$ value. The distance from the $x$ axis up to the corner of the rectangle is $f(s)$, since that's the $y$-value of the vertex.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates of the point $B$ are of the form $(x,x^3)$. That means the rectangle has width $x$ and height $32-x^3$, hence area $A=x(32-x^3)$.  Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

We have 
$$
D = (0, 32) \\
$$

Let have point $B$ the coordinates
$$
B = (x, f(x)) = (x, x^3)
$$
then
$$
A = (0, x^3) \\
C = (x, 32)
$$
The area of the rectangle $A, B, C, D$ is
\begin{align}
S 
&= \lVert B-A \rVert \, \lVert D - A \rVert \\ 
&= \lVert (x, 0) \rVert \, \lVert (0, 32-x^3) \rVert \\
&= \lvert x \rvert \, \lvert 32 - x^3 \rvert
\end{align}

This equation includes the probably not intended cases $B$ lying in the left half ($x < 0$)  and $B$ lying above the line $y = 32$ ($x > \sqrt[3]{32})$.

So we restrict us to $x \in [0, \sqrt[3]{32}]$, such that the area simplifies to
$$
S = x (32-x^3) = -x^4 + 32 x
$$
The derivative $S'(x) = -4 x^3 + 32$ has to vanish for a local extremum, we hope for a local maximum:
$$
0 = -4 x^3 + 32 \iff \\
32 = 4 x^3 \iff \\
8 = x^3 \iff \\
x = \sqrt[3]{8} = 2
$$
Then
$$
S_\max = S(2) = 2(32 - 8) = 2 \cdot 24 = 48
$$